# NDISwrapper fix or alternative for Windows drivers under Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, 20.04, ndiswrapper

I'm looking for an alternative to ndiswrapper. I have an old laptop and I want to use my T-Mobile Web'n'Walk PCMCIA card and I can't find a linux driver for it.

The chip is a Marvell 88W8335-Chipset and the driver for the SIM-card chipset is there, but not for the WiFi.

Can I use NDISwrapper or is there an alternative?

Comment: The alternative used to be to use Windows XP driver files and the ndiswrapper mechanism. However, ndiswrapper is poorly supported and hasn't worked properly on any recent Ubuntu version for many years. Sorry. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.